# 3D model isn't visible in Scene graph

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I want to import a 3D object in my AR application but 3D model is not visible in SceneKit's `Scene graph`. I run macOS BigSur 11.1 on MacBook.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vincent, share your model via `https://dropmefiles.com` file sharing service to test it.